# Where does the CSHS inequality really come from

Tags: bells-inequality

I'm reading about Bell's inequalities and hidden variables theory. And I wonder where does the [CSHS inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality) really come from ? I read the [paper](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v23/i15/p880_1) and the inequality we find is
$$\left|P(a,b)-P(a,b')\right|+P(a',b)+P(a',b')\leq 2 \tag{1}$$

while the most common form I found elsewhere is
$$P(a,b)-P(a,b')+P(a',b)+P(a',b')\leq 2 \tag{2}$$

Where does the absolute value disappear ? I don't understand how (2) could be contained in (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, in this paper, the notation $P(a,b)$ is a (joint) expectation value : 
$$P(a,b) = \int d\lambda \rho(\lambda)A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda)= \langle AB\rangle_{ab}$$, where $A$ and $B$ can only take values $\pm1$

You have :

$$-2 \leq A(a, \lambda) (B(b, \lambda) - B(b', \lambda)) + A(a', \lambda) (B(b, \lambda) + B(b', \lambda))\leq 2 \tag{1}$$
because if one of the 2 terms is $2$ or $-2$, the other term is zero, and these are the only possibilities.

Summing on the $\lambda$ with the density $\rho(\lambda)$, we get :

$$-2 \leq P(a,b)-P(a,b')+P(a',b)+P(a',b') \leq 2 \tag{2}$$

Now, considering : $|A(a, \lambda) (B(b, \lambda) - B(b', \lambda))| + A(a', \lambda) (B(b, \lambda) + B(b', \lambda))$, if the first term is zero, the second term is $\leq 2$, and if  the first term is $2$, then the second term is zero, so finally:

$$|A(a, \lambda) (B(b, \lambda) - B(b', \lambda))| + A(a', \lambda) (B(b, \lambda) + B(b', \lambda)) \leq 2\tag{3}$$

Summing on the $\lambda$, we get :

$$\int d\lambda \rho(\lambda)|A(a, \lambda) (B(b, \lambda) - B(b', \lambda)) |+P(a',b)+P(a',b') \leq 2\tag{4}$$

But we have :

$$|P(a,b)-P(a,b')| = |\int d\lambda \rho(\lambda)A(a, \lambda) (B(b, \lambda) - B(b', \lambda))| \\ \leq\int d\lambda \rho(\lambda)|A(a, \lambda) (B(b, \lambda) - B(b', \lambda)) |\tag{5}$$

So, finally,

$$|P(a,b)-P(a,b')|+P(a',b)+P(a',b') \leq 2\tag{6}$$